# Excel - how to filter a list based on another list of partial values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How to extract / filter an inventory list (in range B3:C7) based on a lookup list with partial strings (in range F2:F3)?

[image]

I know that if the filtering strings were complete (not partial) the formula would be `=FILTER(B3:C7, COUNTIF(F2:F3, B3:B7))`.

With a single partial string (for example in cell F2) the formula would be `=FILTER(B3:C7,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F2,B3:B7)))`.

But how to combine the two, i.e. have partial and multiple filtering strings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir, has already provided a proper solution to your query, however here is few other alternatives, which you may also give a try

[image: Formula_Solution]

• Formula used in cell `E7`

```
=FILTER(B3:C7,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRANSPOSE(F2:F3),B3:B7)),ROW(F2:F3)^0)=1)
```

---

• Formula used in cell `H7`

```
=LET(list,B3:C7,
c,B3:B7,
i,F2:F3,
x,--BYROW(c,
LAMBDA(a,(SUM(COUNTIF(a,"*"&i&"*"))>0))),
FILTER(list,x=1))
```

---

• Formula used in cell `K7`

```
=LET(list,B3:C7,
p,B3:B7,
q,F2:F3,
x,MAP(p,LAMBDA(a,IF(SUM(COUNTIF(a,"*"&q&"*"))>0,a,""))),
FILTER(list,x<>""))
```

---

You can also refer that this query has already been solved sometime earlier in `StackOverflow` here is the link which you may refer as well,

**[How to search multiple names from a range and return multiple records in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71445085/how-to-search-multiple-names-from-a-range-and-return-multiple-records-in-excel)**

---

**Edit**

[image]

• Formula used in cell `E7`

```
=FILTER(B3:C7,MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH("*"&TRANSPOSE(F2:F3)&"*",B3:B7)),ROW(F2:F3)^0))
```

However, the other two alternatives which i have shared it works without any change, kindly note that!

---

One more edit to show formula works when the Lookup Values are partial like **Fr** for **France** and **Ge** for **Germany**,

[image: FORMULA_SOLUTION]

---

Comment: The first option works for me (since my current version of MS Excel doesn't support LAMBDA). Many thanks and sorry for duplicating the question.

Comment: Just found a limitation - as soon as there are duplicated or similar lookup values (i.e. one forms a partial string of another) the formula doesn't work as supposed. Try entering _Ita_ instead of _Germany_ in cell F2 and you will see what I mean.

Comment: In `F2` it is showing presently France and not Germany, however when I changed it to `ita` and in cell `F3` it is showing `Italy` it worked by with tweaks let me update the solution for you again!

Comment: Perfect, now it works exactly as I wanted it to :-). Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Alright I have edited to show all aspects.

Comment: If one of the lookup value cells remains empty, the formula will return the entire, unfiltered input list. Any idea how to exclude the empty lookup cells?

Answer (score 3):

One option would be:

[image]

Formula in `E7`:

```
=FILTER(B3:C7,BYROW(B3:B7&"-",LAMBDA(a,SUM(--(IFERROR(FIND(F2:F3&"-",a),0)=1)))))
```

Comment: Thanks but my version of Excel 365 does not support LAMBDA functions. Is there an alternative way?

Comment: @Piotr, are you sure? You got `FILTER()`. What version of Excel have you got? If 365, try to update it.

Comment: Yes, I am. I am using MS Excel for MS 365 MSO (16.0.13801.21072). The version of the Excel itself is 2102 (Build 13801.21106 Click-to-Run). It does support `FILTER()` and uses [spilling](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dynamic-array-formulas-and-spilled-array-behavior-205c6b06-03ba-4151-89a1-87a7eb36e531) but does not recognize `LAMBDA()` nor the related functions (`BYROW()`, etc.).

Comment: @Piotr, then simply update your version under the home menu.

Comment: Updates are managed by my system administrator, so it will take some time.