# Populate table in excel with different reference tables for data input without losing previos data

Tags: excel, input, dynamic, populate

if this question has been asked before, please lead me to it. I'm asking because I don't know how to search for this.

So the scenario is as follows, I have a sales report that needs to have a year, month, country, distribuitor and product columns that are predefined and then next to this, are a values and units columns for data input.

[Table according to description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JOzG.png)

As of today, I've been manually creating the combination of year, month, country, distribuitor and product. But I was wondering if there might be a way to populate this list based on a set of tables or a catalogue of country/distribuitor/product that can be indepently updated when needed, which then, adds the new combinations of country/distribuitor/product at the bottom of the table and multiplys them by all the month/year combinations that are kept in a separate table, while mantaining the data that was input before the changes in the catalogue.

[Idea of how the data should flow and combine to create a data input layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rftyq.png)

I've previously done this with powerquery by combining two predefined tables(A catalogue table and a month/year table), this gives me the proper layout, but if i change the values of one table, when I update, the new table mixes up the input data that was there before the update.

Im also willing to try this in access but i need a way to create a dynamic catalogue so that i don't have to manually copy-paste 12 times the same combination for each year and that times the amount of years that i want to keep in my table... Any help is appreciated

Comment: As a starting point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72226815/excel-how-to-filter-a-list-based-on-another-list-of-partial-values

Answer (score 0):

In order for your sales report to keep itself up to date, you really need three initial tables - Products, Distributors, and Sales.

Products would contain columns [Product Name],[Product Code],[Distributor],[Value per Unit].

Distributors would contain columns [Distributor Name],[Country].

Sales could look like your supplied image 'table according to description'

Set up all the columns in your sales columns to fill with a [VLOOKUP](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-vlookup-function) or [INDEX-MATCH](https://exceljet.net/index-and-match) formula except for [Product Code]. That way if you update the details of a supplier or product, your Sales table updates automatically as well.

I'd also recommend creating a formula for your [Values] column in the Sales table to reduce user error.

You can further reduce user error by using [Data Validation Lists](https://exceljet.net/excel-data-validation-guide) to fill in the [Product Code] column in your Sales table.

[Here's a rough setup!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTtmx.png)

Setting it up like this means you should also be able to use this data in a [Pivot Table.](https://exceljet.net/excel-pivot-tables)

I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I hadn{t thought of using the index-match formula, I'll try it out, but this solves my problem partially, the idea is to have a catalogue of predefined products with their distribuitor and price. so that everytime i add a new product and distribuitor, it takes the product and a set of predefined years and months and puts a row at the end of the table for every month/ year.