# Looking up information from another table. For all instances of "X" word in column 2, return information in column 1

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am currently working with Excel 2016.

My objective is to find all instances of a word in a specific column in another table, and pull the information from a different column in that table to the new table.

For Example:

```
Lookup table
Column 1 (ASSET)      Column 2 (Equipment)       Column...

XXX-BO-01             Boiler
XXX-BO-02             Boiler
XXX-BO-03             Boiler
XXX-BO-04             Boiler
XXX-P-01              Pump
XXX-P-02              Pump
XXX-S-01              Sink
XXX-H-01              Heater
etc...                etc...
```

I am looking for a formula I can use in another table to look in this table for every instance of "Boiler" and return the unique values in Column 1. The new table will be say, 20 rows, I would like the formula to be present in every row in the appropriate column (so if more Boilers are added in the lookup table the new table will automatically populate that information), but return a 0 whenever it has already found all the unique instances of "Boiler" and returned the requested value.

```
The new table would appear as:

Column 1            Column 2          Column...
XXX-BO-01
XXX-BO-02
XXX-BO-03
XXX-BO-04
0
0
0
etc...
```

I am also looking for a version of that formula which will for with multiple variables, such as if I wanted to pull all the information for both boilers and pumps.

Thanks very much in advance.

PS. Things I have tried:

```
(=LOOKUP("Boiler",Table31314415090234[Equipment],Table31314415090234[Asset])
```

```
=LOOKUP(2,1/SEARCH("Boiler",Table31314415090234[Equipment]),Table31314415090234[Asset])
```

Both of these only return the last instance from the lookup table

```
=INDEX(Table31314415090234[Equipment],SMALL(IF("Boiler",Table31314415090234[Asset],0)))
```

This is incomplete and does not work

```
=INDEX(Table31314415090234[Asset], SMALL(IF("Boiler"=Table31314415090234[Equipment], ROW(Table31314415090234[Equipment])-ROW(Table31314415090234[Asset])+1), ROW(1:1)))
```

This returns "#VALUE" I attempted to utilize another answer doing something similar but could not quite crack it.

```
=VLOOKUP("Boiler",Table31314415090234,Table31314415090234[Asset],FALSE)
```

Lastly I tried this but just get "#N/A"

Comment: Do you have access to `=FILTER` ? Else look into INDEX / AGGREGATE

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to search multiple names from a range and return multiple records in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71445085/how-to-search-multiple-names-from-a-range-and-return-multiple-records-in-excel)

Comment: I have ```=FILTERXML``` only by the looks of it. @P.b

Comment: I looked at your other post and the answer within but I was unable to figure out how to transpose it to my use. @Mayukh Bhattacharya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste this (without the headers) in a new sheet:

| A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX-BO-01 | Boiler |  | Boiler | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E1)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E1)))) |  | Boiler | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H1)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H1)))) |
| XXX-BO-02 | Boiler |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E2)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E2)))) |  | Pump | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H2)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H2)))) |
| XXX-BO-03 | Boiler |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E3)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E3)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H3)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H3)))) |
| XXX-BO-04 | Boiler |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E4)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E4)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H4)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H4)))) |
| XXX-P-01 | Pump |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E5)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E5)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H5)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H5)))) |
| XXX-P-02 | Pump |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E6)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E6)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H6)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H6)))) |
| XXX-S-01 | Sink |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E7)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E7)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H7)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H7)))) |
| XXX-H-01 | Heater |  |  | =IF(ROWS($E$1:E8)>COUNTIF(B:B,$D$1),0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/(B:B=$D$1),ROWS($E$1:E8)))) |  |  | =IF(ROWS($H$1:H8)>COUNTIF(B:B,$G$1)+COUNTIF(B:B,$G$2), 0,INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(B:B)/((B:B=$G$1)+(B:B=$G$2)),ROWS($H$1:H8)))) |

---

## POST-COMMENTS EDIT

The AGGREGATE function (as written in this case) returns the row reference of the results which is used in the INDEX function. Since the table is offset from the top of the sheet, one must correct for the row difference between row 1 and the header's row. In order to achieve this, one can either change the INDEX range of reference (say by considering the whole column that hosts the desired column inside the table) or compensate the result of the AGGREGATE result. The following formula (developed from the one you have provided) use the latter technique:

```
 =IF(ROWS($A$6:A6)>COUNTIF(Table31314415090234[Equipment],"Boiler"),0,INDEX(Table31314415090234[Asset],AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Table31314415090234[Equipment])/(Table31314415090234[Equipment]="Boiler"),ROWS($A$6:A6))-ROW(Table31314415090234[Asset])+1))
```

Test it and send feedback.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to utilize this suggestion for my requirements. I have hundreds of sheets I will need to create using this formula so I will need to be able to specify the word to look for, which column in which table to look for it, and which column in that same table to return the values from in the same row as the identified word.

Comment: You didn't mention "houndreds of sheets" as source data. Anyway in my example: you have the data in columns A:B; in columns D:E you have an example of a "filtering" based on a single criteria (specified in cell D1); in columns G:H you have an example of a "filtering based on two criteria (specified in cells G1 and G2). What's preventing you from implementing this technique? Do you need a way to pick a specific column in a specific sheet? Can you grant more information?

Comment: I'm not sure sure if its relevant, but I have approx. 60 different tables which the base information is coming from. This formula will be used to spawn anywhere from 1-15 tables from each table based on how many different types of equipment in each table. (creating roughly 200 tables) I tried this ```=IF(([ASSET])>COUNTIF(Table31314415090234[Equipment],"Boiler"),0,INDEX(Table31314415090234[Asset],AGGREGATE(15,6,(Table31314415090234[Equipment])/(Table31314415090234[Equipment]="Boiler"),([ASSET]))))``` Based on your formula but did not find success. 1/2

Comment: If you have any ideas on what is wrong with that formula or if you require any further information please let me know.  ```[ASSET]``` is the column in the new table which I am trying fill, ```Table31314415090234[Equipment]``` Is the column from the base table where the Equipment name is kept (I.E. Boiler), and ```Table31314415090234[Asset]``` is the column in the base table where I want to be pulling all the unique asset ID's from.  2/2

Comment: This is my current status, ```=IF(ROWS($A$6:A6)>COUNTIF(Table31314415090234[Equipment],"Boiler"),0,INDEX(Table31314415090234[Asset],AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(Table31314415090234[Equipment])/(Table31314415090234[Equipment]="Boiler"),ROWS($A$6:A6))))```  The information it pulls from [Asset] is not correct, it is currently pulling information from 10 rows too low, but does only pull 3 instances. For the position of the tables, the headers of the look up table in the other sheet start at A12 and the new table starts at A5. @Evil Blue Monkey. Any further assistance to correct this would be greatly apprec

Comment: Edited the answer. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you, this works exactly as I needed. Very much appreciated, @Evil Blue Monkey. I was also able to use your original answer to adapt the new answer to multiple variables, and to utilize for other columns and information.

Comment: Glad to read that. Know that you can make it easier to edit the formula using references to other cells' contents. For example you may use a cell to host the keyword Boiler and/or other cells to host references to the needed range (which can be used in a INDIRECT function for example). This way you'll only need to change the values in those cell accordingly to your need and will not have to carefully edit the formula itself.

Comment: Yes! @Evil Blue Monkey, that's actually exactly what I did. Makes making the additional sheets much faster! Do you know how to do the unique function in excel 2016? I've tried a few different options but its not working out quite the way I want. I.e I'm not able to sort it after pulling the values. Lets say I want to pull all the unique values from Table31314415090234[Equipment] and put them in Table157394846232[Asset Type], and then I want to freely alphabetically sort Table157394846232[Asset Type]. If you know how I can accomplish this in 2016 it would be completing my last formula!

Comment: I think that it's pratically impossible via formula and even if it is possible it would be quite demanding to the processor and therefore not really useful. At least as long as you intend to compress all the process into a single formula. You might achieve something spreading the process on multiple cells, but still formulas (although challenging and therefore stimulating) it's most likely not the best way to accomplish the task. The most difficult part would be to order the list. A VBA based solution might be the way to go.